# Issues connecting to Access on a web server via Android

Tags: java, android, ms-access, odbc, dsn

Here is my issue. I'm working on an App for a client so that they can update data into an MS Access database that is located on a web server. The server is set up for ODBC and I do have a DSN set up. I think I'm missing something in the syntax when it comes to actually connecting to the database. With the current code set up I'm getting a "No suitable Driver" exception thrown back.

I replaced the obvious un/pw with "user" and "pass". I also replaced the url with the web server's url address and the database file name with myDB.mdb

Here is my code:

```
//gets the connection driver
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Driver name is incorrect or unable to be found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=D:url/db/myDB.mdb;","user","pass");
        connect.close();
    } catch (java.sql.SQLException ex) {
        // handle any errors
        error.setText(String.valueOf("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage()));
    }
```

I'm new to connecting to a database in Java so I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I would appreciate any help I can get.

I've been researching this online for a few hours and have gotten no where.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to MS Access Database using Android App. If yes, then it's not possible to connect as the way you are trying. Search for any specific API that will support your android app to connect to MS-Access Database which is Sitting on Your PC.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for the proper API to use? I'm basically just looking to update and add new data to a database.

Comment: You Are trying to connect MS Access Database, Instead if you are connecting to SQL-Server or sybase like databases then i should suggest you to go through http://amitku.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/how-to-connect-and-access-sql-database-server-from-android-app/ and http://jtds.sourceforge.net/ . Search Something simlar like this hope this links will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't connect directly from your phone to a database that's sitting on a server somewhere.

A better solution would be to set up a web service on the server that allows you to read/update the database, and then call that web service from the Android app.

Comment: By web service you mean something like a php script?

Comment: For example, yes. It depends what is running on your server. If it runs PHP, fine. But you can write web services in any other language, too. Basically, a web service is just a web page that returns data in XML or JSON format...[here are some examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242355/php-web-service-example).